# Custom property behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I have a class which members must be mapped to an external memory.
When I read their value, I want to read it from the memory, and when I set it I want to write it to the external memory.

I have tried to implement the descriptor protocol to have these fields behave like properties:

```
class PagedField(object):

    def __init__(self, memory, page, offset, count, converter=bytearray):
        # memory is just a subclass of bytearray with some fancy methods
        self.memory = memory
        self.page = page
        self.offset = offset
        self.count = count

        # The value is automatically converted during get()
        self.converter = converter
        self._value = None

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        self._value = self.converter(self.memory.get(self.page, self.offset, self.count))
        return self._value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value is None:
            value = ''

        val = str(value)                # Everything is written to the memory as a string
        val = val[0:self.count]         # cut to the maximum allocated length
        while len(val) < self.count:    # fill with 0s
            val += chr(0)

        # Store and write to memory
        self._value = val
        self.memory.set(page_index=self.page, data=str(self._value), offset=self.offset)
```

However, I must be missing something. If I try to assign the fields, the field itself is over-written with the value. Example:

```
mem = bytearray(100)

class Foo:
    x = PagedField(mem, 0, 0, 10, str)

f = Foo()
f.x = "hello"
print type(f.x)
```

shows that f.x is now a string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `class Foo` doesn't inherit from `object`

Comment: You are right, that fixed it! Could you please explain why? I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2 you need to inherit form `object` to get a new-style class. Only new-style classes support descriptors (and properties). Therefore, you need change `class Foo:` into `class Foo(object):`. In Python 3 this is not necessary because old-style classes are removed.